# Delete a pushed item in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete an object by id from firebase I pushed it long time ago.

```
  delete: function(){
    var id = $("#locations").val();
    firebase.database().ref('/suppliers/' + this.props.params.id + '/locations/' + id).remove();
  },
```

In this code Id represent a pushed Id format like this `-L1-b6qyyR52a7RGkw1c`based on a select bar where I choose what I want to delete.

But the function fail with no error but nothing is deleted.

Comment: perhaps a try catch block so that we get an error message of some sort: ` delete: function(){
    
  try {
  var id = $("#locations").val();
    firebase.database().ref('/suppliers/' + this.props.params.id + '/locations/' + id).remove();

}
catch (error) {

   console.log(error)
}}`

Comment: Can you share your firebase DB screenshot ....!

Answer (score 1):

Considersing `suppliers` is root node. use `suppliers/` instead of `/suppliers/`

Try this function

```
      delete: function(){
        var id = $("#locations").val();
        var ref = firebase.database().firebase.database().ref('suppliers/' + this.props.params.id + '/locations/' + id);
        ref.once("value")
       .then(function(snapshot) {
         snapshot.ref.remove();
       });
    }
```